# What do the platform tags in manifest.xml mean and when are they added?

Tags: ros, manifest.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't seem to find the answer to this in the [manifest xml reference](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rospkg/html/manifest_xml.html), but in some manifest files I see tags like:

```
  <platform os="ubuntu" version="9.04"/>
  <platform os="ubuntu" version="9.10"/>
  <platform os="ubuntu" version="10.04"/>
```

What do they represent and when are these tags added?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11588/what-do-the-platform-tags-in-manifest.xml-mean-and-when-are-they-added?/) by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4541 on 2011-10-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've experimented with them on our backend to test platform-specific builds (there are flags in rosmake that can make use of them).  In practice, it turns out to not be good in this role. While in theory it's nice to store this information with the code, it means that the code has to be updated/released every time you compute this information, which is not scalable for the number of packages that are now in use.  That's why you tend to not see them very up-to-date.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2